# App crashes frequently after SDK integration

Tags: flutter, here-api

I've successfully integrated the HERE Flutter SDK into my app.
I succeeded to display here maps with markers and to get results from `RoutingEngine.calculateCarRoute`. Very often, especially when debugging and when navigating back the app crashes since the integration. Here's one stacktrace from a recent crash:

```
Build fingerprint: 'OnePlus/OnePlus5/OnePlus5:9/PKQ1.180716.001/2002242003:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 32060, tid: 32185, name: Thread-44  >>> appidentifier <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 0x788f7c37d0
    x0  000000788f86cd00  x1  0000007878b82220  x2  000000788f7c37d0  x3  0000000000000000
    x4  000000785bcf9001  x5  0000000000000000  x6  00000078785efdc1  x7  00000000000000a2
    x8  000000788cb79104  x9  0000000000000002  x10 0000000000000001  x11 0000000000000000
    x12 000000786f615800  x13 0000000000000001  x14 0000000000000000  x15 0000007882dfe6c0
    x16 000000788e03f7c0  x17 000000792ccae05c  x18 0000000000000010  x19 000000788f65c158
    x20 0000007882dfe620  x21 0000007882dff588  x22 0000007882dfe5f0  x23 0000000000000001
    x24 000000788f944180  x25 0000000000000006  x26 000000788fccf400  x27 00000078718357d0
    x28 0000000000000004  x29 0000007882dfe680
    sp  0000007882dfe5d0  lr  000000788cb23bf0  pc  000000788f7c37d0
backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000000001c37d0  [anon:libc_malloc:000000788f600000]
    #01 pc 000000000024bbec  /data/app/appidentifier-84DIJI7JrxXFbuOqpeuANg==/lib/arm64/libheresdk.so
    #02 pc 000000000024b9d8  /data/app/appidentifier-84DIJI7JrxXFbuOqpeuANg==/lib/arm64/libheresdk.so (here_sdk_library_execute_callbacks+44)
    #03 pc 000000000000525c  <anonymous:0000007880d80000>
```

As you can see the crash comes from the Here SDK --> `libheresdk.so (here_sdk_library_execute_callbacks+44)`

Any idea how to solve the problem? Currently, the SDK is not usable due to these issues.
My SDK version is "HERE SDK for Flutter (explore Edition) - Version 4.3.2.0"

**UPDATE**

My app does the following:

- Display the current location on a map
- Get Autocomplete Suggestions and a location for a search entry
- Get Route Information a.k.a. Directions for current location to chosen destination
- Display this route information with a polyline on a map.

I can reproduce this crash by following exactly this flow and by then navigating back from the second map screen to the `car route` screen.

**UPDATE 2**:

SDK 4.3.3.0.86 doesn't crash but causes ANR when I do not touch the app and map for a while. When I then force quit the app, I get:

```
I/appidentifier(14261): Thread[5,tid=14294,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0x73f03fc800,peer=0x146019a0,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
I/appidentifier(14261): 
I/appidentifier(14261): Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
F/crash_dump64(15038): crash_dump.cpp:550] failed to attach to thread 590: Permission denied
```

Comment: Since you mention a back press. There's a Flutter bug which can be prevented like this: https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/blob/master/examples/latest/explore/flutter/hello_map/android/app/src/main/java/com/here/sdk/examples/hellomap/MainActivity.java - can you check if this will fix your issue? This workaround is not part of all example apps, since it seems not related to the HERE SDK.

Comment: no, cannot be related as the app also crashes when I put it in a SliverAppBar and the bar gets collapsed. my guess it that you keep references which shouldn't be kept within the map

Comment: Probably there are still some issues, since the SDK is in Beta state. The next release 4.3.3 should bring some improvements.