# SDK prevents `Hot Reload` & `Hot Restart` from working

Tags: flutter, here-api

When using the Here SDK for Flutter `Hot Reload` & `Hot Restart` stop working. I can tell this because when I switch to another branch which doesn't use the HERE SDK these two features work as supposed.

Within the HERE SDK integration branch these tasks will run endlessly. This makes the SDK practically unusable as recompiling takes too long for a smooth developer experience.

I can force a `Hot Restart` by moving the HERE map with my fingers. Something within the SDK is preventing this essential Flutter feature from working. Is there something I've overseen?

My SDK version is "HERE SDK for Flutter (explore Edition) - Version 4.3.2.0"

Comment: Which IDE are you using? With Android Studio 3.6 it seems to work. Although sometimes I experience the same issues. Doing a restart helps.

Comment: I experienced this in IntelliJ Idea and Android Studio first, but also in Vs Code since a week or so

Comment: The funny thing about it is that it seems to be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61944779/app-crashes-frequently-after-sdk-integration
When I swipe the map the Hot Reload suddenly seems to work, sometimes it also crashes though

Comment: Can you please provide some error logs ? you can refer more here at our documentation : https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-explore/4.3.2.0/dev_guide/index.html

Comment: Hey @HEREDeveloperSupport - We also have this problem with the SDK Navigate Flutter (version 4.5.4). Thank you